# Allowed memory size exhausted in PHP loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code:

```
 15 $users = pg_fetch_all($result);
 16 $chart_data = array();
 17 foreach ($users as $value)
 18 {
 19         //var_dump($value);
 20         $temp = array();
 21         $temp['label'] = $value['id'];
 22         $temp['y'] = $value['sum'];
 23 print_r($temp);
 24 /*
 25 echo "<pre>";
 26         var_dump($temp);
 27 echo "</pre>";
 28 */      
 29         array_push($chart_data,$temp);
 30 }
 31 echo count($chart_data);
```

When I run my code, I get the following error message:

```
[Thu Apr 28 17:23:39.278844 2016] [:error] [pid 24321] [client 10.63.8.104:58362] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /var/www/localhost/htdocs/audit/index.php on line 21
```

This is a sample of the output I get from the print_r():

```
Array ( [label] => 12 [y] => 0.0021 )
```

I can't see how line 21 is problematic here. Maybe I need to explicitly reset temp to an empty array??
Not sure too but any suggestions welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: `array_push($chart_data,$temp);` You're building a big array inside your loop; arrays require a lot of memory, that's what's using it all

Comment: i see.  i was wondering if that was the issue.  i'm trying to build data points to use with canvasjs.  I guess I'll have to try to reduce the amount of data I plot / get back.  But other than that, what else can i try?

Comment: Another option is to increase the amount of memory that you allow your script to use

Comment: Why don't you `SELECT id AS label, sum AS y` or somesuch? Then you don't have to do this.

Comment: You can try increasing the max limit with `ini_set('memory_limit','256M');` A lot of shared hosts won't allow it though

Comment: @AbraCadaver I like that!  I upvoted but can you also post as an answer?

Comment: @Happydevdays: I already suggested it in mine.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yup, you have.  But I don't know if it matters on this forum or not, but AbraCadaver answered first... so I thought I would extend the opportunity to post as an answer.  Maybe it doesn't matter?

Comment: @Happydevdays: He posted it in the wrong place (comments), like 14 seconds before my fully fleshed-out answer was posted. Does "who was first" matter? Nope. Do you need an answer written twice, though? Also no. Does it matter either way? Not really. Were you wrong to ask him to post an answer? No. Is his answer (now posted) good? Yep. Shall we move on to more interesting things? Sure :)

Comment: @Happydevdays: Thanks.  I and many others hesitate to post those as an answer because invariable the OP comes back with some reasons or at least a statement of some super complexity that they failed to mention in the question.  Glad you didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the memory issues, it looks like you are just trying to change the associative array indexes from the column name to something else.  Try doing it in the SELECT:

```
SELECT `id` AS label, `sum` AS y FROM `somewhere` . . .
```

Then your original `$users = pg_fetch_all($result);` should contain what you want.

Comment: Why backticks only sometimes? Consistency is king! (Or is this a PostgreSQL oddity? I don't know that DBMS).

Comment: sum is reserved but it looked funny as the only one so I made a little pattern or symmetry or something.

Comment: Heh okay well it's very pretty

Answer (score 4):

It's fairly self-explanatory, isn't it? You perform an `array_push` into `$chart_data`, on each iteration, so **`$chart_data` gets bigger on each iteration**. Eventually, with your server settings as they and with your data as it is, you run out of memory before you get to the end.

Either handle less data or give yourself more memory. Your PHP settings are giving you 128MB, which is high but not insane. You can increase it if you are sure that you need to.

An alternative would be to revisit the need to create this huge array in the first place. You appear to be doing it only to rename the keys, which seems extremely wasteful. Consider renaming them in your database query so that they are what you want from the start. Then you can just iterate over the rows in sequence, and you don't have to read the entire dataset into memory all at once.

Comment: Well, it wasn't clear to me, no.  Now it is... but I always assume it's a bug in my code vs. really believing that I have a legit case of insufficient memory.  and sure enough... it was bad code.

Answer (score -1):

you can increase the allowed memory for all but I think this can be useful for you

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M'); // write this line before your code
```

Comment: Letting a badly-written PHP script consume 1GB RAM? Hmm, what could possibly go wrong.

Comment: I am simply giving answer to the question asked, which is "Allowed memory size exhausted".

Comment: And your answer proposes a poor solution to that problem. The mentality of "just throw more resources at it" causes so much unnecessarily bloated software and teeny tiny battery life on my mobile phone that it makes my head bleed!

Comment: Yes but you have given that answer, I have just given other option